# Cannot get Javascript to navigate to a page

Tags: javascript, url, browser

I have this very simple "page":

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>Handling...

<script>
var token = location.hash.toString().substring("#access_token=".length, location.hash.indexOf("&"));
var t = "/ri/auth/fbLogin?token=" + encodeURIComponent(token);
console.log(t);
// t is now /ri/auth/fbLogin?token=blablablablablabla
setTimeout(function() {
window.location.href = t;
}, 2000);
</script>

</body></html>
```

For some reason, the script always redirects to itself first, but without the hash. That version of the script then redirects to the intended URL, but with an empty `token`.

I've tried `window.location = t` and `window.navigate(t)` as well, but no luck there. That timeout is also a failed attempt at getting  it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How silly. Turns out the script worked after all, but the page that it navigated to redirected back to the referrer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting
var token = location.hash.toString().substring("#access_token=".length, location.hash.indexOf("&"));
var t = "/ri/auth/fbLogin?token=" + encodeURIComponent(token);

Inside of your timeout function.

Comment: I don't think that will help. Via the `console.log`, I see that the value of `t` is correct.

Comment: The value of t is correct yes, but it may be a scope issue because you are not passing anything to your function inside of setTimeout, in this case I see no reason why you cannot just plop the code in there.